# In Azure DevOps pipelines, can I use both my free 1800 minutes and a paid pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My setting looked like this when I only had the free tier:

[image]

Now when I started paying for a job it looks like I lost my free 1800 minutes.
[image]

I was under the impression that I would get *another* job if I paid for it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use them, but not simultaneously (you are still limited to 1 parallel job, since you only bought one). If you use your own agent (instead of the hosted), you can still use free 1800 minutes. Right now you are asking how do I have 1800 free minutes on top of unlimited paid minutes which makes no sense :)

Comment: Why doesn't it make any sense? I get 5 Basic licenses to DevOps for free and if I buy one license I have a total of 6. So why couldn't I in this case have two parallel jobs, one which has unlimited minutes and one with 1800 minutes?

Comment: because you are not getting free parallel job, you are getting free minutes. thanks for the downvote ;)