# purchased an parallel build agent, but free is gone

Tags: azure-devops

I've just purchased a parallel build agent, but after that the free agent with 1800 minutes is gone.
Is that correct?
It was not clear from the documentation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Azure DevOps pipelines, can I use both my free 1800 minutes and a paid pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54501041/in-azure-devops-pipelines-can-i-use-both-my-free-1800-minutes-and-a-paid-pipeli)

Comment: parallel host CI/CD or self host CICD？ It's better to provide your screenshot in Organization settings > Pipelines > Retention and parallel jobs > Parallel jobs. Which could make question more clearly

Answer (score 0):

If you are buying Microsoft-hosted CI/CD. This is the expected behavior.

> You can pay for additional capacity per parallel job. Paid parallel
>   jobs **remove** the monthly time limit and allow you to run each job for
>   up to 360 minutes (6 hours). Buy Microsoft-hosted parallel jobs.
>
> *[Source Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops#relationship-between-jobs-and-parallel-jobs)*

Please notice our **official description**. After you bought one paid parallel job, you will not get a new additional parallel job. It's just move the limitation for your prefer free job. That's why your free is "gone".

[image]